# bind same result of sql as one string

Tags: mysql, binding, grouping

How to bind the same results of `MySQLi` query as one string. Like I have column "`visitor_country`" which contains country codes of visitors. I have 5 columns of PK and 5 columns of AU. I want to `echo` them in my web page. How can i group same country codes? and display like:

```
   |PK 5|
   |AU 5|
```

this is my database table
[image: this table contains 5 rows of PK and 5 of AU]

I want to get all the country codes from visitor_country and bind all same country codes and echo them

Comment: Did you mean `rows` instead of `columns` => `5 columns of PK and . 5 columns of AU`

Comment: yes, I mean rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to take a look at MySQL's [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) function

```
SELECT `visitor_country` FROM `tablename` GROUP BY `visitor_country`;
```

This really should do the trick: take a look at [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b16d/1)

Comment: Mind giving more information? An example of the data and the result you wish to get?

Comment: @FahadMaqsoodQazi, I've changed my answer with a working example.

Comment: Glad to hear that.